# Code coverage from multiple devices or iOS Versions

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode7, code-coverage

Is there a way built into Xcode7 (or Xcode8) to show code coverage from multiple devices?  For instance, with code like this:

```
if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    guard let startOfNextMonthAnswer = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: startOfThisMonth, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue:0)) else {
        return nil
    }
    startOfNextMonth = startOfNextMonthAnswer
} else {
    let oneMonthComponent = NSDateComponents()
    oneMonthComponent.month = 1

    guard let startOfNextMonthAnswer = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(oneMonthComponent, toDate: startOfThisMonth, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0)) else {
        return nil
    }
    startOfNextMonth = startOfNextMonthAnswer
}
```

With just looking at coverage from one test run, you will always either the `if` or the `else` code as untested.

Could one aggregate the code coverage data from this iOS9 simulator and an iOS 7 device to see comprehensive code coverage?  While it wouldn't be helpful for this specific test, could you even consolidate coverage data between the iOS8 and iOS9 simulators?

Are there any ways built into Xcode (non-server) to handle this?

Comment: I know that Xcode 9 now allows you to run tests in parallel that should allow you to run the suite with multiple devices at the same time, but I haven't tried it to see if the coverage reports are blended or not.